# Performance testing with PhantomJS

Tags: node.js, load-testing, phantomjs

I am using Google soy templates and have developed both Server-side and client-side rendering solutions. I want to benchmark them using performance tests. While benchmarking the client-side part, I want to wait till all the javascript actions are performed to calculate the *actual* response time.

I had tried below but it doesn't solve my purpose.

- [PhantomJS](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs) supports accessing single page and querying required information on the page, but is doesn't provide any option to simulate the concurrent connections
- [Nodeload](https://github.com/benschmaus/nodeload), provides the ability to load test a server, but doesn't have any option to retrieve the information from the page.

Is there are other framework that I can use to do both Load testing as well as page scraping?

Answer (score 11):

You can do that with PhantomJS (and SlimerJS): just create a new `page` instance for each request. The below script is a full example. (Warning: it is quite verbose if your page requests lots of other resources.) The number on the left is milliseconds since the script started.

On my machine example.com points to localhost, and the bottleneck was Apache. E.g. When I run with N=30 it takes about 5 seconds to run. If I then run it immediately again, it took 0.75 seconds (because enough Apache instances had already been spun up). When I tried with N=100 it took about 12 seconds, and created huge load on my poor notebook.

This was enough to prove to me that the 6-connection limit of a browser was not being hit, and all 100 connections were genuinely running at the same time. If that is still not parallel enough for you, use a bash script to start, say, 8 instances of PhantomJS (assuming you have 8 cores).
NOTE: All page instances are sharing a browser cache. So I see a single request for jQuery, for instance.

The exact same script runs on SlimerJS, but the behaviour is quite different. There is more overhead in starting each instance it seems, but more importantly each has its own disk cache. So my test time involved 30 requests to the Google CDN for JQuery!

(Asking if PhantomJS can be configured to not share cache, or if SlimerJS can, should probably be another StackOverflow question, as I don't know off-hand.)

```
/**
 * This calls N instances of URL in parallel
 */
var url = "http://example.com/";
var N = 30;

var cnt = 0;

function onResourceReceived(response) {
    console.log((Date.now() - startTime) + ':' + response.stage + ':' + response.url);
}

function onResourceRequested(requestData, networkRequest) {
    console.log((Date.now() - startTime) + ':Request:' + requestData.url);
}

function onCompletion(status) {
    ++cnt;
    console.log((Date.now() - startTime) + ':COMPLETE(' + cnt + '):' + status + ':' + this.url);
    if (cnt >= N) phantom.exit();
}

var startTime = Date.now();
for (var i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    var page = require('webpage').create();
    page.onResourceReceived = onResourceReceived;
    page.onResourceRequested = onResourceRequested;
    page.open(url + "?i=" + i, onCompletion); //Append i to allow tracking
}
```

Comment: `If that is still not parallel enough for you, use a bash script to start, say, 8 instances of PhantomJS`, I use phantomjs with [parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) to scrape/screenshot a bunch of sites in 3 different resolutins, so if you go the bash way, consider parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at LoadBooster (https://www.loadbooster.com). It uses PhantomJS/CasperJs to distribute tests. PhantomJS/CasperJS will parse and render every page, execute the client-side script. The PhantomJS/CasperJS approach is easier to write test scenarios to support complex AJAX heavy Web 2.0 app.

Disclaimer: I work for LoadBooster.